# Отказано в доступе phpMyAdmin

Tags: php, sql, phpmyadmin

Установил wordpress на локальный сервер, в phpMyAdmin сменил пароль для root. После перезагрузки страницы получаю ошибку:

```
phpMyAdmin не смог установить соединение с сервером MySQL. Проверьте хост, имя пользователя и пароль установленные в конфигурационном файле config.inc.php и удостоверьтесь, что они соответствуют данным полученным от администратора сервера MySQL.
```

В файле config.inc.php указал новый пароль, но не помогло. При авторизации с этим же паролем в MySql через терминал проблем не возникает. Где еще нужно указать новый пароль для phpmyadmin? Можно ли в нем отключить автоматическую авторизацию и вводить правильный пароль вручную?

MacOS, MAMP